Hivemetastore - create external db failing due to kerberos authentication
I have a hive metastore setup on derby. I want to create an external table. The data sits on a remote hdfs location. I am using kerberos auth. My hive-site and core-site and hdfs-site have all the required properties. However I get the below error even when I run a simple query like - create database testdb;
Show databases works.
Execution error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.qs.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:Got exception: org.apache.hadoo.ipc.RemoteException Client auth method 'SIMPLE', mechanism '' is not supported. kerberos only)
Have the keytab file, cache and required env variables setup.
